# Hide Keyboard on Textfield when it Editing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How to hide a keyboard when I am using DateTime picker on `UITextField`. When I click on `UITextField` that time first show a keyboard than it shows DateTime Picker on selected `UITextField`.
Please give me appropriate solution for this.

Comment: do you want the keyboard to be replaced with a UIDatePicker?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. _Please give me the code_ isn't the way this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Set the textField delegate like below image

(A)

[image]

(B)

[image]

2.Add textField delegate methods

Swift

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Implement your Date Time Picker initial Code here
  return false
}
```

Objective C

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   // Implement your Date Time Picker initial Code here
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the textField delegate to the object in which the textfield is initialise

   `textfield.delegate = self` //object which will handle textfield delegate methods.
2. Implement the textfield delegate methods

   ```
   (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
       if ([textField canResignFirstResponder]) {
           [textField resignFirstResponder];
       }

       return YES;

   }

   (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       // add your method here

       return YES;
   }

   (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

   }
   ```

In Swift

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method

}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric..I didnt noticed that. Added now.

Comment: Thank you for adding the Swift version!

Answer (score 0):

In the below delegate method of **UITextField** you can return false so that keypad won't come, and you can add the code to show your datepicker.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            //Your code to show datepicker

            return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Keyboard notifications` to find find out wether Keyboard complete shown or not. When you find out keyboard is shown then show `DateTime` picker on your current `textField`.

Here is a code for Keyboard Notifications

```
let center = NotificationCenter.default
center.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                   name: .UIKeyboardWillShow,
                   object: nil)

center.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                   name: .UIKeyboardWillHide,
                   object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the inputView of the the textField to replace the keyboard with a date picker

```
dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
```

Like so

Or you can prevent the keyboard from showing up in the first place by using the

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

You'll need to return false and add your custom code to show a datepicker before

Answer (score 0):

Text field picker View use this

```
    let pickerView = UIDatePicker (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 240, width:    self.view.frame.size.width, height: 250))
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    pickerView.minuteInterval = 30
    textField.inputView = pickerView

    pickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourvc. datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    let toolbar = UIToolbar (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 56))
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    items.append(
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done".localized(lang:  self.language!), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourvc.pickerDoneClicked(sender:)))
    )
    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
    toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar


   func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker)
    {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    print("date picker --->%@",sender.date)
    }

  func pickerDoneClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
   {
    textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
   }
```